# Ansible in a cloud image

Tags: ssh

I am looking into using Ansible to manage my systems and going through its documentation I found a recommendation to run the Ansible commands on a cloud image rather than my local laptop.

My understanding is that Ansible basically acts like an SSH user to the systems it manages.  So wouldn't this recommendation mean that I would be storing authorized keys to all my systems (with sudo-enabled users!) all in a single cloud image?

In other words if that cloud image is ever compromised I am royally screwed.

Is this a correct risk assessment or am I not understanding something?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud aside, if Ansible becomes compromised, then it exposes all the servers it manages.

The question becomes: how best to mitigate that risk.

If you use your laptop, then anything you do on the laptop potentially exposes Ansible. Browsing, installing, etc. A dedicated, locked down image that is not used for personal activity is better, in *that* regard.

Ansible puts all your eggs into one basket and then, to quote Andrew Carnegie, "watch that basket!"

Comment: Your point about my laptop vulnerability is a good one that I hadn't thought of.   Perhaps my solution is to run a small linux VM on the laptop and have its volume encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to deploy the authorized public keys to your Ansible-managed systems with the "from=" parameter with a small set of Ansible servers per managed node (two or three would be ideal; you want more than one for redundancy, but casting too wide a net here defeats the purpose). Unfortunately, you can't limit with the "command=" parameter because Ansible creates arbitrary names for the commands it runs to execute playbooks.

Beyond that, it's pretty much a matter of applying general hardening principles to the Ansible servers to protect the keys.